# Getting error 69 code blocks in error.h

Tags: windows, x86, operating-system

I am working with turboc but now I have started with code blocks to run c++ programs. I am getting the same error

> Build: Debug in First (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===| c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits\gthr-default.h|69|fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory| ||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))

I have done the research on the Google but didn't find the solution. Even I have changed the compiler settings. Even downloaded the `error.h` file and inserted in the `Mingw` bits folder.
I am still unable to get out of this. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some sort of concurrency mismatch issues. Please uninstall both the compilers and try installing the new one. I also was once stuck into the same issue. Then I installed Dev C++ and everything is fine now. I recommend **Dev C++** for the same.
http://filehippo.com/download_dev-c/